# How to make a column editable on click Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am displaying some records in a table using ngFor. I want to make a column editable when it is clicked.

```
<tr *ngFor="let cd of descriptionCodes; let i = index">
  <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>
    {{cd.code}}>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select class="form-control border-gray" id="codeType" [(ngModel)]="cd.codeType.id" (change)="onCodeTypeChange(i, cd.id)" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
      <option *ngFor="let type of codeTypes" [ngValue]="type.id">{{type.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>{{cd.description}}</td>
</tr>
```

What I want if I click on a particular code then It Should be editable and If I click on any description then it should be editable as well. I also want to make single field editable at a time if I have selected other field then previous field that was edited should not be editable now.

Can anyone please provide me any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have one property that denotes the status of the column and set it on the click event of the td.

Please check the code below:

```
<tr *ngFor="let cd of descriptionCodes; let i = index">
 <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
 <td (click)="setCodeEdit(i)">
   <span *ngIf="!cd.canEditCode">{{cd.code}}></span>
   <input *ngIf="cd.canEditCode" type="text" class="form-control"  />
 </td>
 <td>
   <select class="form-control border-gray" id="codeType" 
  [(ngModel)]="cd.codeType.id" (change)="onCodeTypeChange(i, cd.id)" 
   [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
  <option *ngFor="let type of codeTypes" [ngValue]="type.id">{{type.name}}
    </option>
   </select>
  </td>
  <td (click)="setDescEdit(i)">
   <span *ngIf="!cd.canEditDesc">{{cd.description}}></span>
   <input *ngIf="cd.canEditDesc" type="text" class="form-control"  />
 </td>
 </tr>
```

Component Side:

```
setCodeEdit(index){
  this.descriptionCodes.forEach(t => t.canEditCode = false)
  this.descriptionCodes[i].canEditCode=true
}

setDescEdit(index){
  this.descriptionCodes.forEach(t => t.canEditDesc= false)
  this.descriptionCodes[i].canEditDesc=true
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: somehow it's working fine but I would not like to make other fields editable when I am editing a field.... like I am editing a code at that time I dont want to make any other fields as editable only that particular field should be editable ..

Comment: @warrior, have you implemented the entire code Because I have taken **canEditCode** and **canEditDesc** properties for that purpose only

Comment: Yes I have implemented it and for first time It's woking fine but if I select the second code then first code that was selected earlier is also editable ..

Comment: @warrior, please check the updated code now. I have implemented the function for that.

Comment: @warrior, Please upvote my answer if it has helped you

Answer (score 0):

you can save all cells information like isedit or editable property and after click on cell set isedit true and write new tag inside cell with *ngIf="cell.isedit" then write inside it input or select or ... and do certain action after change or blur like set isedit false or send update request

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have to capture the checkbox value that can be done by:

**HTML**

```
<tr *ngFor="let cd of descriptionCodes; let i = index">
  <td><input type="checkbox" (change)="checkboxFunction($event)"></td>
  <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{cd.code}}" [readonly]="readOnly" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <select class="form-control border-gray" id="codeType" [(ngModel)]="cd.codeType.id" (change)="onCodeTypeChange(i, cd.id)" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
      <option *ngFor="let type of codeTypes" [ngValue]="type.id">{{type.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>  <textarea type="text" class="form-control" value="{{cd.description}}" [readonly]="readOnly"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
```

and in your TS file:

**TS**

```
checkboxFunction(event){
   if(event.target.checked){
this.readOnly = 'true';
}
}
```

Comment: @Ekaanth Thanks but I dont want to make those columns editable on click of checkbox.. I want to make that column editable when I click on that particular column

Comment: I will Edit the answer :)

Comment: And using this I think same column of all rows would be editable but I would like to edit only particular column