# Angular 6 - click to make a div editable

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Using Angular 6, I have the html below and would like to click the edit text to make the div containing Detail$.Title editable.

Im trying to do it as per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48375522/how-to-make-a-column-editable-on-click-angular-4)

```
 <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="card text-left" >
      <div class="card-header text-secondary">Title <small class="pull-right text-danger" (click)="setTitleEdit()">Edit Text</small></div>
      <div class="card-body">
          <span *ngIf="!cd.canEditCode">{{Detail$.Title}}></span>
          <input *ngIf="cd.canEditCode" type="text" class="form-control"  />
          <p class="card-text text-secondary">{{ Detail$.Title}}</p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

intellisense doesn't like the forEach or canEditCode below, I know Im missing something, just not sure what, Im unsure where the canEditCode is coming from in the linked post. In my ts file Detail$ is an object containing the data returned from a call

```
getEventDetail(): void {
    this.data.getDetail(this.id)
      .subscribe(data => this.Detail$ = data);
  }
setTitleEdit(){
    this.Detail$.forEach(t => t.canEditCode = false)
    this.Detail$.canEditCode=true
  }
```

Comment: If `this.Detail$` is an array, then `this.Detail$.canEditCode = true` will be invalid and if `this.Detail$` is an object, then `t.canEditCode = false`will be invalid.

Comment: What type is `Detail$`? Usually, having a `$` at the end of the variable name suggests that it's an observable, but that's not how you use it. Also, is `this.tDetail$` a typo or is it another variable?

Comment: Detail$ is just of type Object (Detail$: Object;), fixed the typo

Comment: I saw you changed the `tDetail$` typo now, good. Can you create a stackblitz to show us what you're doing exactly?

Comment: will do, give me 10 mins...

Comment: That's why you get typescript errors, forEach only works on arrays. If you want to have `canEditCode` you need to define it or declare Detail$ as `any`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try like this

```
<div class="col-sm-6" *ngFor="let item of detailItems">
    <div class="card text-left">
        <div class="card-header text-secondary">{{item.title}}
            <small class="pull-right text-success" (click)="item.canEditCode = true">Edit</small>
            <small class="pull-right text-danger" (click)="item.canEditCode = false">Close</small>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
            <input *ngIf="item.canEditCode" [(ngModel)]="item.name" type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

> [(ngModel)]="item.name" make two way binding to item property (name)

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-item-edit)

Comment: @DarkW1nter happy to help

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easier to use native **HTML** input for editing and viewing with **ngModel** and style options.
Simply like this:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="title" class="editable">
```

And for **CSS** class:

```
.editable{
   border:none;
   outline:none;
   background:transparent;
}
```

That's should work.